# ehcache implementation in tomcat 4 nodes

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, caching, ehcache

We have multiple applications in tomcat that have 4 instances . also we have 2 tomcats and each have 4 nodes.

we want to use the cache mechanism to get the properties from database and store into cache, this cache can be used in multiple application which are in same JVM.

so , my question is , how we can it be achieved ?
which cache can be used ?
what configuration can be modified ?

we want to use ehcache , is that good idea ? we want to load properties while start up the tomcat server and store the properties in cache , so that other services also can be used.

is there any tomcat plugins available for cache ?

Comment: any solutions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that is you have multiple webapps, they are in different class loaders. So if you want a common cache (and a single `CacheManager` instance), it needs to be in a common class loader.

This can indeed be done in tomcat but requires ehcache in tomcat libs (the one made available to applications. I don't remember the details). Then, if you store without serializing, you also need the cached classes in tomcat libs. By serializing (like storing offheap), I think it shouldn't be needed.